# Either of the checkbox can only be true

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

**Situation**
I have two form control check boxes. I am trying to write a code that will allow only either of them to be true.

[image: Two form control check box]

**my code is**

```vb
Sub CheckBox2_Click()
  If CheckBox1.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
  Else
     If CheckBox2.Enabled = True Then
         CheckBox1.Enabled = False
     End If
  End If    
End Sub
```

I have this code in module and have assigned the same macro for both the checkboxes. I get run-time error 424. I beleive this is very basic problem but I unable to dela with it.
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use Radionbuttons (OptionButtons) for that?

Comment: Yes, I know the radio button is good option but the checkbox looks better when a print out is made. Actually, it is just preference. I rather dont like to use radio buttons though.

Comment: You don't break general UI best practice because of "looks better". I as a user expect the possibility to be able to chose _both_ checkboxes, when they're present. Anything else is a bug.

Comment: As a programmer, I realize the best practice but the users for this program do not accept the suggestions and therefore, have to adjust according to the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the following way. Form check boxes do not have a click `event`, as ActiveX ones have. You should associate the next sub **to both of them**. The check boxes I tested, have their names as "Check Box 1" and "Check Box 2". You have to change yours according to the reality in your case, Please, copy the next code in a **standard module** and then associate it to both used check boxes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FormCheckBoxChange()
     If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).value = 1 Then
        Select Case Application.Caller
           Case "Check Box 1": ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 2").value = -4146
           Case "Check Box 2": ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").value = -4146
        End Select
     End If
End Sub
```

Use instead of the used check box names, the appropriate ones for your case.

In case of Form text boxes, their value is not `True` and `False` as in case of ActiveX ones. It is `1` and `-4146`...

Comment: So that means, I used the code for ActiveX. I see. I tried your suggestions and thats what I was looking for. Good to learn this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to enable/disable the checkboxes.

Following code makes sure that either one of both boxes is checked.

```vb
Public Sub checkbox2_onClick()

Dim oCb1 As Object
Set oCb1 = Table1.Shapes("Checkbox1").OLEFormat.Object

Dim oCb2 As Object
Set oCb2 = Table1.Shapes("Checkbox2").OLEFormat.Object

If oCb2.Value = 1 Then oCb1.Value = 0


End Sub

Public Sub checkbox1_onClick()
Dim oCb1 As Object
Set oCb1 = Table1.Shapes("Checkbox1").OLEFormat.Object

Dim oCb2 As Object
Set oCb2 = Table1.Shapes("Checkbox2").OLEFormat.Object

If oCb1.Value = 1 Then oCb2.Value = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I get an error "Object required (Error 424)". And I guess enable/disable was the wrong choice.
@lke, Please note, I have form control checkbox and not active control  and I am using excel 365.

Comment: You have to access the checkboxes differently - please update "Table1" according to your needs.

Comment: Actaully, both the solutions, worked for me. Thank you